# What is it? Based on a real person

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> Once a fruit has won a different fruit. Undesirably!

What fruits are we talking about?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think what you are referring to is when

> Halle **Berry** won the [Golden **Raspberry** award for Worst Actress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Raspberry_Award_for_Worst_Actress) in 2004.

which is an

> Undesirable achievement

Comment: Great job. I think the puzzle should have a Knowkedge tag. Not many people know this.

Answer (score 4):

Are you:

> Grapefruit?

because

> By adding 'fruit' to the fruit 'grape,' you get 'grapefruit,' a different fruit entirely?

Comment: rot13(Gur guvaxvat: Bar sehvg pbhyq or cneg bs gur anzr bs gur bgure sehvg vf tbbq. Ohg jvaavat yvgrenyyl zrnaf jvaavat urer.)